# How to group menu by Alphabet in shopify?

Tags: shopify

How to group menu by Alphabet in shopify?
I want to group dropdown menu like this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5VR3.jpg]

I am new to shopify, I tried to group menu by trying to get the first letter using this code

```
{% assign first_letter = {{ link_primary.title | slice: 0 }} %}
```

but it is giving me following error

```
Liquid syntax error: Unexpected character { in "{{{{ link_primary.title | slice: 0 }} }}"
```

Comment: what have you tried? Where did you fail? Like it asked now, your question is far too broad to be answered. Your problem is underdefined, and this feels a lot like you're asking us to do your work, not to help you.

Comment: I am new to shopify, I tried to group menu by trying to get the first letter
using this code
{% assign first_letter = {{ link_primary.title | slice: 0 }} %}

but it is giving me error for {{{{

Comment: add that info to your question, as well as the **verbatim error**. I think this is pretty obvious when you ask a question: Give us all the info you have.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the {{ }} around the link title.

You can assign the first letter like:

```
{% assign first_letter = link_primary.title | slice: 0 %}
```

Then just check whether it's within a certain range, for example A-D, E-H etc.